# NSString Error - Interface type cannot be statically allocated

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

I'm trying to create an NSDictionary object where the keys are defined with the number of the song, along with the information. I'm getting the above error when trying to define the NSNumber that is being passing into the method:

```
+(NSDictionary *) initWithMPMediaItem:(MPMediaItem *) song andSongNumber: (NSNumber *)songCount{

NSString *songKey = @"%@ Song Title", songCount;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want to use:

```
NSString *songKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Song Title", songCount];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I know what the stringwithformat method does.